# Cannot able to access json array in php , it returns null and Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, ios, arrays, json, warnings

I am trying to send json array to php and insert multiple rows in to table

Problem:

Php:

1. Not able to access the decode JSON array - array count returns nil
2. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

When I print JSON string it gives me the below data

```
[
    {
        "email" : "",
        "Name" : "Ddd",
        "contact2" : "",
        "ontact1" : ""
    },
    {
        "email" : "",
        "Name" : "Ddd",
        "contact2" : "",
        "contact1" : ""
    },
    {
        "email" : "",
        "Name" : "Dddddr",
        "contact2" : "",
        "contact1" : ""
    }
]
```

But when I am trying to access that using php that shows me a error

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php

    $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $array = json_decode($inputJSON, true);

    echo count($array);

    foreach($array as $item) {
        $uses = $item['Name'];
        echo $uses;
    }

?>
```

Error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

So I tested the array in php using ,

```
Isarray() || Isobject funtion but it print null
Count() funcions provide 0 

 var_dump($array); result NULL
```

But I decode the array and check the result in iOS, it gives the array as response

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

But in php I am not able access the array.

Not sure if there is any mistake in iOS code. In iOS I have `NSMutableDictionary` that is stored to `NSMutableArray` and then `NSArray`.
When I parse the `NSMutableArray` I get the same problem.

**iOS code:**

```
func saveToCloud(){

    var mutablearray = NSMutableArray()

    var dict = NSMutableDictionary()

    var eachRow = textfieldarry  as [UITextField]
    for eachField in eachRow {
        let index = eachRow.indexOf(eachField)
        let  data =  eachField.text!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())


        dict[keys[index!]] = data
    }

    mutablearray.addObject(dict)

    var TonNSarray = NSArray(array: mutablearray)
    var url = "myurl/file.php "

    JsonParseTOSaveCloud(TonNSarray, urlstring: url, successfullResponse: "Success", alertmessage: "not")
}
```

**Saving to Server:**

```
func ok_JsonParseTOSaveCloud(dict:AnyObject,urlstring:String,successfullResponse:String,alertmessage:String){

    let json:NSData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
    var d = NSString(data: json, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("jsonstr\(d!)")
    let urlString = urlstring

    urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())!

    let httpRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)

    httpRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    httpRequest.HTTPBody = json

    let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Accept" : "application/json", "api-key" : "API_KEY"]

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

    let postDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(httpRequest, completionHandler: {(data: NSData?, reponse: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in

        if data == nil {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                let alert = UIAlertView(title: alertmessage, message: "you are no longer connected to the Internet", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss")

                alert.show()

            })
        } else {

            print("data\(data)")

            //let jsonResult = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers))
        }

    })

    postDataTask.resume()
}
```

Note: When I check in php, like this it works. That is when I give the Jsonstring or jsonarray directly it works.

```
<?php

    $json  = '[
    {
        "email" : "",
        "Name" : "Ddd",
        "contact2" : "",
        "contact1" : ""
    },
{
    "email" : "",
    "Name" : "Ddd",
    "contact2" : "",
    "contact1" : ""
},
{
    "email" : "",
    "Name" : "Dddddr",
    "contact2" : "",
    "contact1" : ""
}
]';

$array = json_decode( $json, true );

foreach($array as $item) {
    $uses = $item['Name'];
    echo $uses;
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Use `var_dump($inputJSON)` and make sure there's nothing extra in the input. Also use `json_last_error()` when `json_decode()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you.  var_dump($inputJSON) gives me this  string(0) ""  and  json_last_error() gives  me int(0)

Comment: If the input JSON is empty, how do you expect to get anything when decoding it?

Answer (score 0):

With God Grace solved my problem
The mistake in my original code was, the accessing of data.First i used for each so it gives me warning.Then from the link 
http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/decode.php, i  got the  accessing like this , then it worked.

```
       $location = $data[0]['email'];
```

Then we use a combination of numeric and associative array syntax to access the desired element in multidimensional array.

Comment: Don't see how this can possibly work if `$data` is null.

Comment: var_dump($data) return string(0) "", but when ecode the data and send it to the ios it have the data.It have data ,

Comment: There must be something else going on, like you reassigned the variable or you're doing these two steps in different scopes. Also, first you said `var_dump($data)` is `NULL`, now you say it's `string(0) ""`. It can't be both. But either way, you can't do `$data[0]['location']` with that value of `$data`.

Comment: There's also no `location` key in the JSON you show in the question.

Comment: For this answer to be useful for future readers, you need to explain what was wrong with the original code, and **how** this fixed it. Otherwise, it's just cargo-cult programming.

Comment: Why did `foreach` give an error? If you can subscript it with `$data[0]` then it's an array, and `foreach` should not complain. Also, why did `var_dump()` say it's null if it's actually an array that you can access with `$data[0]`?