# Json_decode returns string(0) ""

Tags: php, json, null

I am trying to pass data from ios to server.

Php code :

```
<?php
   $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $data = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);
   var_dump($data);
?>
```

This gives me `string(0) ""`. I don't know whats the meaning of this.

```
        echo $inputJSON; gives nothing 
       var_dump($inputJSON); returns  string(0) ""
```

When i print the json-string it gives me a valid string

Please find the full codes of this problem in another question of mine

[Cannot able to access json array in php , it returns null and Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474431/cannot-able-to-access-json-array-in-php-it-returns-null-and-warning-invalid-a?noredirect=1#comment60564240_36474431)

Comment: Does the `$inputJSON` have values?

Comment: echo $inputJSON; gives nothing 
  var_dump($inputJSON); returns  string(0) ""

Comment: php://input this is worked me before.

Comment: Please see my edited question,am sending data from ios to php.

Comment: I have less knowledge in php, plz tell me what is the meaning string(0) "" , is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With God Grace solved my problem-

pass true to convert objects to associative arrays, so accessing  numeric/associative array like this.

```
$var = $data[0]['key'];
```

Then we use a combination of numeric and associative array syntax to access the desired element in  multidimensional array.

But if i trying to  var_dump($data); is retun null.

Reference tutorial: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/decode.php

Answer (score 2):

I have created an example for you that what i am talking:-

1.My both file (`php` code file and `json` string file) in the same working directory.Check:- http://prntscr.com/apkbp9

2.`json` string file content should be:-

```
[
    {
        "email" : "",
        "Name" : "Ddd",
        "contact2" : "",
        "ontact1" : ""
    },
    {
        "email" : "",
        "Name" : "Ddd",
        "contact2" : "",
        "contact1" : ""
    },
    {
        "email" : "",
        "Name" : "Dddddr",
        "contact2" : "",
        "contact1" : ""
    }
]
```

Check here:- http://prntscr.com/apkbx0

3.`php` code file content:-

```
<?php
   $inputJSON = file_get_contents('input.txt');
   echo $inputJSON;
   $data = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);
   echo "<pre/>";print_r($data);
?>
```

Check here:- http://prntscr.com/apkc6x

Output on my browser:-  http://prntscr.com/apkcoi

You can use `CURL` like below:-

```
<?php
   function url_get_contents ($Url) {
        if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
            die('CURL is not installed!');
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }
    $inputJSON = url_get_contents('php://input');
    echo $inputJSON;
    $data = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($data);

?>
```

For more reference about `CURL` :- http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

**Note:- if both will not work, then first you need to save your `json` data in a file with extension `.txt` and then you can use both code given above, just by putting the full path of that text file.**

Comment: Yes that i did the same , if you read my question means you can see that.

Comment: from ios to php, we cannot define a php file.the http post taken as file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: i think may be the problem is i am sending json array, so may be that is not valid

Comment: Thank you so much +1 for quick answers

Comment: But the json data are dynamic, so its not possible with save each time.I  think in my case thats not my problem.

Answer (score 1):

fisrt you should check is your url is correct or not. If every thing is right but still its not showing the response use curl functionality such as [alter native of file_get_content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979802/alternative-to-file-get-contents)